# gets can't get correct unique_cas_token

Tags: memcached

When I add one key in memcached, and then want to get `unique_cas_token` by `gets` operation. But the `unique_cas_token` returned from memcached is always `zero(0)`, why?

```
gets test
VALUE test 32 5 0
test
END
```

Answer (score 0):

start shell include -C param; cause cas_enabled no.